# How do I parse a double with optional decimal seperator

Tags: c#, .net, regex

i want to parse numbers with unit like

```
3cm
3.44 cm
12,33  mm
```

the following expression does exactly what i want

```
(([0-9]*(?:[,.]?[0-9]*?))[\s]*(cm|mm))
```

but the problem is it also matches things like

```
cm 22.1   cm
```

in this case it ignores the number and matches the first cm only, how do i ignore the first cm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update the first number match quantifier from zero or more (*) to one or more (+):

```
(([0-9]+(?:[,.]?[0-9]*?))[\s]*(cm|mm))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?\s*(?:cm|mm)
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/qJ8qW5/2

Answer (score 1):

Like others said, you need to change the quantifier `*` to `+` where `*` represents zero or more and `+` represents one or more. If you want to match also the numbers like `12,533.45 cm`, then you could use the below regex.

```
[0-9]+(?:,[0-9]+)*(?:\.[0-9]+)?\s*(?:cm|mm)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/eX9yA4/6)

Comment: Note that `\d` in .NET matches Unicode digits by default.